# C++ vector of array of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, dynamic-arrays

I want to have a dynamic structure which I could iterate on, there will be unknown number of entries and  known number of strings for each entry. I thought that vector of array of strings could be the way, however I get error while compiling this:

```
vector< array<string, 5> >
```

error: `invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::array<std::basic_string<char>, 5u>'`

What am I doing wrong? and if this is kind of the way - how would I add/get   values to/from this structure?

Comment: Include all the headers you need to include. And make sure you have C++11.

Comment: compile with `-std=c++11`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you include all these three headers?

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>
```

This compiles just fine:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::string, 5> > myVec;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the second part of the question - how do I add items to this vector (dynamicly)?

Comment: Using emplace_back:  
    "myVec.emplace_back();"

or push_back:  
    "myVec.push_back(std::array<std::string, 5>());"